# html including another html menu - dropdown does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I have looked at many examples including:
[JavaScript menu dropdown onClick does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863166/javascript-menu-dropdown-onclick-does-not-work)

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

However I can not get this to work. I am including a master dropdown menu in all my html pages. When I test the dropdown menu on its own it works; however, when I include the menu in another HTML, using Ajax, the dropdown children do not appear when I select the parent.

The menu is Heading.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Select Person</title>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application">
<meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }


</style>
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Fav and touch icons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                               <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>  

<div id="login"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');">

    <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Activities <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Activity - E1 Administration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activity - E1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Camps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hikes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Major Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pen Pals</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>

</div> <!-- /container -->

<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/heading-ajax.js"></script>
```

The associated js is heading-ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', 'dropdrown-menu', function(){
    $('.dropdrown-menu').toggle();
});
}); // end document.ready
```

The html that includes the above is SelectPerson.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Select Person</title>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application">
<meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  .form-signin {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 19px 29px 29px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  }
  .form-signin .form-heading,
  .form-signin .checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .form-signin input[type="text"],
  .form-signin input[type="password"] {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 7px 9px;
  }
  .myheader {
    display:flex;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .myimg {
    width: 130px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .pull-right {
    text-align: right;
  }

  /* Tooltip container */

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltiptext {
visibility: hidden;
width: 120px;
background-color: #555;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px 0;
border-radius: 6px;

/* Position the tooltip text */
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 125%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -60px;

/* Fade in tooltip */
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 1s;
}

/* Tooltip arrow */
.tooltiptext::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

</style>
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Fav and touch icons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                               <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>    

<div id="selectPerson  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');"> 

    <div id="includedContent"></div>


    <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="contactForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-signin">

                    <h2 class="form-heading">Select Cub Scout</h2>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input id="cubName1" name="cubName1" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Cub name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /row -->
    </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->

<div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>

<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/selectPerson-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="js/heading-ajax.js"></script>
```

And the jQuery is selectPerson-ajax.js:

```
$(function(){
$("#includedContent").load("Heading.html"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the dot for the class `dropdrown-menu` in this line:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', 'dropdrown-menu', function(){...
```

should be

```
 ... '.dropdrown-menu', ...
```

Comment: Hi Johannes I made the change and it still does not work: $(document).ready(function () {
 $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', '.dropdrown-menu', function(){
  $('.dropdrown-menu').toggle();
 });
}); // end document.ready